# Trying to understand why <li> is a block level element

Tags: css, html

Am currently learning about the differences in block level and inline elements.

The key thing that I've read about block level elements is that they have a new line before and after them e.g. the `<p>` element. I've read that the `<li>` element is a block level element too but I'm not sure why as although it has a whole line for itself, it is followed on the line above and after with other `<li>` elements...it doesn't have those new lines.

Here's something I've read online which confused me:

> So if you have a paragraph
>   (block-level), and you end that paragraph and begin another paragraph, there
>   will be blank line between them. Same thing between a header and a paragraph,
>   between two headers, between a paragraph and a list, between a list and a table,
>   etc. This is a useful clue as to what a block-level element is.

Comment: Maybe the paragraph is just a clue.

Comment: There are no such things as "lines" in block layout. There are only block-level boxes. Line boxes pertain to inline formatting. Whoever wrote that is either making things up, or grossly oversimplifying things.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, so it's the padding and margins that are creating the space between some block level elements. The following quote in the article at ahuka.com/?page_id=119 made me think it was more like a line break between elements. "Block-level elements generally begin on new lines. In practice, most browsers insert a blank line between any two block-level elements. So if you have a paragraph (block-level), and you end that paragraph and begin another paragraph, there will be blank line between them"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mistaken whatever you read.

Just keep this in mind:

**Block level elements start in the next line.**

The line before and after is due to the margin / padding of the element. Do not confuse both. Block level elements like heading, paragraphs and li start in the immediate next line, just like "div" tags. You can increase this vertical space by adding a margin or padding to the element.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, so it's the padding and margins that are creating the space between some block level elements. The following quote in the article at ahuka.com/?page_id=119 made me think it was more like a line break between elements. "Block-level elements generally begin on new lines. In practice, most browsers insert a blank line between any two block-level elements. So if you have a paragraph (block-level), and you end that paragraph and begin another paragraph, there will be blank line between them"

Comment: Just keep in mind, block level elements always start in the immediate next line. The margin and padding can be adjusted to make the line between 2 block elements bigger or smaller, at your will.

Answer (score 0):

`<li>` is not a list element but a list element:

`<ul>` or `<ol>` is the list element and as you can see in my snippet below, it produces new lines.

```html
<ul style="background-color: slategrey;">
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Hello</li>
</ul>
<ul style="background-color: rgb(160, 176, 192);">
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Hello</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: While looking at block level elements, I can see why `<ol>` and `<ul>` elements are considered that way because as you've shown they do leave the new lines before and after themselves. However the `<li>` elements within aren't doing that...but they're still considered block level elements. That's what I'm not understanding.

Or perhaps the new lines before and after isn't a 100% rule everytime?

Comment: @jobe - the lines are made by the default 1em margin that is placed before and after the `<ol>` and `<ul>`. If you remove that margin there is no whitespace [like this example](http://jsbin.com/deyosasoze/edit?html,css,output) where I remove the margins. [Read a simple explanation on the display property here on CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/)

Comment: Ah ok thanks, so it's the padding and margins that are creating the space between some block level elements. The following quote in the article at http://www.ahuka.com/?page_id=119 made me think it was more like a line break between elements.

"Block-level elements generally begin on new lines. In practice, most browsers insert a blank line between any two block-level elements. So if you have a paragraph (block-level), and you end that paragraph and begin another paragraph, there will be blank line between them"